# "Presenter view" for second monitor?

Tags: video

I have a laptop, which is connected to a projector. Is there any program or method, which can give me a small window on the laptop's screen, of what is displaying on the projector? Sort of a "presenter view" -- but not for Powerpoint -- for anything that may be on that projector screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/LionelJouin/PiP-Tool can do so for any *window*, which is almost what you want.