# Two screen desktop presentation setup with second screen not facing presenter

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, presentations

I have 4850+ `.rtf` and `.doc` files which I need to present arbitrarily to a group of people monthly, on a screen which I cannot see (to maximize the number of people who can see the screen, cable length limitations, etc, I sit behind/beside the screen). I need to scroll these files as the group reads from them, and I need to be able to read from them as well at the same time.

*I cannot use PowerPoint* - these are `.rtf` and `.doc` files, there are too many to convert to `.ppt` manually, and I'd be concerned about verifying accurate conversion if it were possible in an automated manner.

I am not satisfied with using mirrored screens, as I need to take notes while managing this all, and also do not want to show my full desktop to the group (much less my notes).

Is there a way I can get a live "picture-in-picture" window of the second monitor, so I can read, see where the mouse is to scroll, etc, while still being able to perform other tasks with my computer?

I am somewhat limited to Windows 10 at this time.

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/q/740351/16468

Comment: can also use OBS (open broadcaster software) and set a "scene" as your presentation monitor. This will allow you to see it as well as see the mouse on your primary screen. This is the same software game streamers use to manage what windows get streamed while the viewer can only see what is selected.

Comment: @Narzard caused my OS to lock up 4x times that night, so might not be a good fit :/. Otherwise seemed an adequate solution.